# Javascript does not correctly change the inner html

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my Javascript...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validator() {
         var x = parseInt(document.MyForm.textnuming.value);
         alert(x);


        if (document.getElementById('rbsm').checked) {
            if(x == 0){
                var y = 7.70;
            }
            else if(x == 1){
                var y = 8.41;
            }
            else if(x == 2){
                var y = 9.10;
            }
            else if(x == 3){
                var y = 9.65;
            }
            else{
                var y = 9.65+(0.71*x);
            }
        }


        else if (document.getElementById('rbme').checked || document.getElementById('rbla').checked) {
            if(x == 0){
                var y = 13.84;
            }
            else if(x == 1){
                var y = 14.95;
            }
            else if(x == 2){
                var y = 15.99;
            }
            else if(x == 3){
                var y = 17.04;
            }
            else{
                var y = 17.04+(1.09*x);
            }
        }


        else if (document.getElementById('rbmi').checked) {
            if(x < 3){
                var y = 3.99;
            }
            else{
                var y = 4.28;
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Error!");
        }

        document.getElementById(testing).innerHTML = y;





}




</script>
```

And below it is my HTML form...

```
<body>
<form name="MyForm">
    <input type="radio" name="rbsize" value="small" id="rbsm" />Small<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rbsize" value="medium" id="rbme" />Medium<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rbsize" value="large" id="rbla" />Large<br />
    <input type="radio" name="rbsize" value="mini" id="rbmi" />Mini<br />
    Number of Ingredients: <input type="text" name="textnuming"  width="2" maxlength="2" />
    <input type="button" value="Press me!" onClick="validator()" />

</form>
<div id="testing">Price!</div>




</body>
```

My script is successfully executed except for the very last part. I want the div "testing" to say the whatever the var y is after going through the script but it doesn't change..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('testing').innerHTML = '' + y;
```

Without quotes, `testing` is trying to reference a variable called `testing` instead of getting the `<div>` with `id='testing'`.

Answer (score 0):

last sentence is wrong

should be: `document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = y;`